# Question mark shows up in Terminal App after installing a package into a non-existent conda environment

Tags: macos, terminal, conda, apple-m1, miniconda

(In case it's relevant: I have a MacBook Pro with an Apple M1 chip.)

I made a mistake installing a Python package into a conda virtual environment `pymer4` that didn't exist (`conda install -c ejolly -c conda-forge -c defaults pymer4` ). Then a question mark appears every time I open the terminal app in the `/Users/apple` directory. When I `cd` into any other directory, I don't see the question mark.

[image]

Old questions (like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75751/why-does-the-folder-icon-in-my-terminal-have-a-question-mark-overlaid)) on this issue didn't have satisfying answers. Things I tried but failed:

1. **Deleting conda-related parts from `.zshrc`**: The question mark disappears, but when I reinstall conda, it comes back. This solution isn't viable because I need conda.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/apple/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/apple/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/apple/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/apple/opt/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

2. **Deleting `pymer4` from `/Users/apple/.conda/environments.txt`**: The problem persists.
3. **Uninstalling the `pymer4` package**: Same as above.

I'm very confused why installing a package into a non-existing virtual environment would cause this. If anyone knows how I might fix it, very much appreciate it!!

Comment: There is no such thing as "*installing into a non-existent environment*" - not specifying an environment assumes active one or **base**.

Comment: I guess my main question is, why the question mark appears now when I open terminal in `/Users/apple`,  but not before. I uninstalled Miniconda and used Anaconda to fix this issue, which is ideal.

Comment: I would have instead rolled back revisions on the environment in which it was installed (see [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html?highlight=revisions#restoring-an-environment)).